# Connecting to a SQL Server DB

Tags: perl, odbc, dbi

I’ve been trying to connect to a SQL Server DB in Perl since yesterday, and it’s a failure. I use the `DBI->connect` function, but I got error saying the data source and the driver are not found. I use that string:

```
'dbi:ODBC:mydb:myhost\myinstance'
```

I’m not really sure the string’s correct. Any idea?

EDIT: here’s the error I got:

```
DBI connect('***:***\***','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002)
at Collector.pl line 137
```

Answer (score 3):

The format of the DBI connect string for ODBC is 'dbi:ODBC:DSN_name' or 'dbi:ODBC:DSN=DSN_name' (for connections using Data Source Names (DSNs). In that case DSN_name needs to be the name of a data source you created with the ODBC administrator. This situation is slightly more complicated in Windows 64 bit environments as there are 2 ODBC administrators, one for 32 bit applications and one for 64 bit applications (you cannot mix the two).

So, first, work out if you Perl is 32 bit or 64 bit executable - you can usually see this from the output of perl -V (look for archname but there are other indications too). Then find the right ODBC Administrator depending on how your perl was built and create the data source with it. Lastly, change your DBI connect string as above.

There are also so called DSN-less connections that do not require a DSN but instead you name the DRIVER and any attributes required to connect to the database.

There differences in what DBD::ODBC does if you use 'dbi:ODBC:DSN_name' instead of 'dbi:ODBC:DSN=DSN_name' which you can read about [ODBC - The Connection Process](http://www.martin-evans.me.uk/node/70).

You can find out more about 32/64 bit ODBC and where to find the right driver manager at [64 bit ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/64-bit.html). You can find out about DBD::ODBC and connections at [Drivers, Data Sources and Connection - Perl DBI/DBD::ODBC Tutorial Part 1](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_1.html).

Comment: DBI->data_sources('ODBC') seems to return an empty array…

Comment: So do you have any data sources? Look in the ODBC Driver manager to see if any are defined.

Comment: the problem is I’m writing a Perl script for production servers (a lot). I am going to figure it out, and I’ll be back

Comment: Then use DSN less connections i.e., use 'dbi:ODBC:DRIVER={my driver name here};some_attr=some_value;another_attr=another_value;'. It avoids creating DSNs altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems to work ok,

```
use DBI;
 #
$dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:mysql:DBNAME", "root", "password" )
  or die "Connection Error $DBI::errstr\n";
```

N.B. Please Check you have the required modules installed.